# How can I solve an equation with matrices in Matlab (or Maple)?

Tags: matlab, matrix, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to solve the following equations in Matlab and Maple. 
It concerns the derivation of the Mass-, stiffness and damping matrix for a 2 Degree of Freedom Shear based building idealization.

I need to solve mass matrix M from:

`E'.M.E = I` with `E = [0.459 0.834;0.888 -0.551]`, and `I = [1 0;0 1]`

And solve Matrix K from:

`E'.K.E = W²` with `W² = [26.39² 0;0 73.83²]`

And solve Matrix C from:

`E'.C.E = 2.Z.W` with `W = [26.39 0;0 73.83]` and `Z = [0.017 0;0 0.009]`

Thank you

Comment: Those matrix equations are all of the form `A' X A = B`, where `X` is the unknown, and `B` is symmetric. Therefore, you can derive `X` by solving a linear system of 3 equations in 3 unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
M = E.I.E'
K = E.W^2.E'
C = E.(2.Z.W).E'
```